# Saving object to core data with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform

I'm trying to save an object to Core Data which is fetched from Parse, but i'd like only those which doesn't contain a name which is already in database:

```
func fetchFromParse() {

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Medicine", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Medicine")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                let medicine = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context)

                if let  name = object["medicineName"] as? String,
                    amount = object["amountQuantity"] as? String {

                        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name != %@", name)
                        self.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

                        do{
                            let fetchedEntities = try self.context.executeFetchRequest(self.fetchRequest) as! [Medicine]
                            //save to  Core Data


                            medicine.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                            medicine.setValue(amount, forKey: "amount")

                        } catch let error as NSError{
                            print(error)
                        }

                        do {
                            try self.context.save()
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fetch data from Core Data

```
func fetchFromCoreData() {

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        medicines = results  as! [Medicine]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }


}
```

i put the in viewWillAppear:

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
        //fetching data from Parse

        fetchFromParse()
        fetchFromCoreData()
        tableView.reloadData()

    } else {
        //fetching data from Core data
        fetchFromCoreData()
        logOutButton.enabled = false

    }
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions how to repair it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kind of have everything, just not hooked up. You shouldn't be instantiating and inserting the new object until after you've executed and checked the fetch. You currently execute the fetch but don't check to see if there is a duplicate. Both of these issues need to be resolved, something along the lines of:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Medicine", inManagedObjectContext: context)
let query = PFQuery(className: "Medicine")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        for object in objects! {

            if let  name = object["medicineName"] as? String,
                amount = object["amountQuantity"] as? String {

                    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name)
                    self.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

                    do{
                        let fetchedEntities = try self.context.executeFetchRequest(self.fetchRequest) as! [Medicine]
                        //save to  Core Data

                        if fetchedEntities.count <= 0 {
                            let medicine = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context)
                            medicine.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                            medicine.setValue(amount, forKey: "amount")
                        }
                    } catch let error as NSError{
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
        }

         do {
              try self.context.save()
         } catch let error as NSError {
              print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does't work. It saves entity with the same name again and again

Comment: Typo in the predicate, we want to check for no matches, not no differences. Corrected in the answer

Comment: It works!!! Could you also tell me why at the same time i cannot fetch the data and see them in tableView? Only after second launch of the app ?

Comment: You need to reload the table after saving the context. Don't forget to vote and tick answers that help and solve :-)

Comment: should i put: self.tableView.reloadData()   in viewWillAppear after those two fetching functions ?

Comment: It doesn't work.. But anyways, thank you for previous solutions.

Comment: You need to check that the table view outlet is set, and that it's called on the main thread (IIRC it is, otherwise the code data handling is also on the wrong thread)